# jQuery Type Error this is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am not sure why I kept getting this "Type Error: $refinesearch.replacewith(resultsrefinesearchwrap_content); is not a function".

My code looks like this:

```
var resultsheader = $('#IDX-resultsHeader'),
    resultslinknew = resultsheader.find('#IDX-resultsLinkNew'),
    resultslinkmodify = resultsheader.find('#IDX-resultsLinkModify');

var resultsrefinesearchwrap = resultsheader.find('#IDX-resultsRefineSearchWrap');

var resultsrefinesearchwrap_content = '<div class="nmr_refinesearch">';
    resultsrefinesearchwrap_content += resultsrefinesearchwrap.detach().html();
    resultsrefinesearchwrap_content += '<div class="nmr-btn gray">';
    resultsrefinesearchwrap_content += resultslinknew.detach().html();
    resultsrefinesearchwrap_content += '</div>';
    resultsrefinesearchwrap_content += '<div class="nmr-btn gray">';
    resultsrefinesearchwrap_content += resultslinkmodify.detach().html();
    resultsrefinesearchwrap_content += '</div>';
    resultsrefinesearchwrap_content += '</div>';

var $refinesearch = $('.refinesearch');

$refinesearch.replacewith(resultsrefinesearchwrap_content);
```

It's just a simple detach and reinsert into some new HTML container.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replacewith should be replaceWith.

```
$refinesearch.replaceWith(resultsrefinesearchwrap_content);
```

Comment: That was it?! Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 2):

`replaceWith()` is case sensitive use it with **Capital** 'W'

```
$refinesearch.replaceWith(resultsrefinesearchwrap_content);
```

Answer (score 1):

`replaceWith()` and JavaScript are case sensitive. Capitalize your w and you will be set.

[jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)